# LIKE with % on column names

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

Here is my query that results in a syntax error:

```
SELECT * 
FROM account_invoice,sale_order
WHERE sale_order.name LIKE %account_invoice.origin%
```

The account_invoice.origin field contains the text of sale_order.name, plus other text as well, so I need to match sale_order.name string anywhere in the account_invoice.origin string.

I'm using PostgreSQL 8.4.

Comment: looks like an openerp query?
Shouldnt it be "sale_order.name = account_invoice.origin" to avoid matching "SO123" with "SO1234"

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM account_invoice,sale_order
WHERE sale_order.name LIKE '%'  || account_invoice.origin || '%'
```

`%` needs single quote because the pattern is a string.

`||` is the operator for [concatenation](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-sql/2000-07/msg00294.php).

Comment: Thanks, your solution solved my problem.  It turns out that I also had my where clause backwards.  It should have been: WHERE account_invoice.origin LIKE '%'  || sale_order.name || '%'

Comment: why couldn't they(postgres) just use  + operator?