# Postgres how can I get column inside a quote

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-9.4, partial-index

First and foremost I am using postgres version 9.4 . I am trying to create a partial index on this query

```
select DISTINCT ON(city,state)city,state,zip from zips where city ilike 
'%' and state ilike '%' limit 10
```

My issue is that I do not know how to **put columns inside the quotes '%'** so that the partial index looks like this

```
 select DISTINCT ON(city,state)city,state,zip from zips where city ilike 
    '{city}%' and state ilike '{state}%' limit 10
```

What is the correct method to put columns inside a single quote mark ? I have been looking all over the place. Right now my partial index looks like this

```
CREATE INDEX "Location_Search"
   ON zips (city ASC NULLS LAST, state ASC NULLS LAST)
   where city ilike 'city%' and state ilike 'state%';
```

Which is obviously not helping because postgres is treating the **'city%' and state ilike 'state%'** as variables and not columns. I have a search-box where users type in the city and state fields so I want to optimize. Any help would be appreciated ...

Comment: I don't understand why you think you need a partial index. Just create one index on each column `create index on zips (city)` and `create index on zips (state)`. But a condition `state ilike '%'` will **never** use an index because it select all rows anyway

Comment: And even if you define such an index, it is pretty useless, as the condition `city LIKE city||'%'` is **always** true for non-null value. It is an expensive way of writing `city is not null`

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 WHERE column_name LIKE column_name||'%'
```

see this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13274679/like-with-on-column-names)